# Bind all models from parent ViewModel to their own separate ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im using a method to get all the models from the database. Depending on what the state of the button is (located in the parent ViewModel) I want to load different variables in the view. I've tried fixing this issue by making a ViewModel for every model to get the variable I need.

The issue is that I can't seem to get this solution to work. In the image below I use LinQ to bind a ViewModel to the Model. But whatever I try, the select method remains unknown or simply doesn't execute.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> InitialLoadAsync()
{
    return await DataLogic.GetTableAsync<ApparaatInventaris>().Select((ai) => new ApparaatInventarisViewModel(ai, this));
}
```

Not allowed to link images, if you rather see an actual image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSyjW.jpg

Any insight or even a different approach is highly appreciated. (First time posting on stack and don't really know what to include or not, if more information is needed just ask)

Edit 1:

```
var apvListVM = new ApparaatInventarisListViewModel();

apvListVM.DataLoadingSettings = new ListDataLoading
{
    InitialLoadAsyncFunc = apvListVM.InitialLoadAsync,
    UpdateDataAsyncFunc = apvListVM.UpdateDataAsync
};
```

Comment: Please include the code that calls `InitialLoadAsync`.

Comment: Yes, using Xamarin forms MVVM

Comment: I think `Select` should  return `ApparaatInventaris` , but `(ai) => new ApparaatInventarisViewModel(ai, this)` is invalid in this scenario.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you revise your problem statement into a question? Reading the post, I'm not sure if your issue is with Xamarin.Forms not showing anything or if this is a problem with your Linq statement.

Comment: Thank you, As far as I know its an issue with LinQ. I can solve this issue by not using LinQ and using elements of Xamarin forms instead.